# Displaying MySQL data as JSON in ASP.NET, Restful web service?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, json, restful-url

I Followed [This](http://www.packtpub.com/article/displaying-mysql-data-on-asp.net-web-page) to Read MySQL DataBase and Display Tables in ASP.net.

But I want to Display Those Tables as the Part of JSON data,
For Example :
This is Employ Table,
[image]

And I wnat to Display this Data in the form  of JSON
Like :

```
[
{
    "id" : 1,
    "first_name" : "John",
    "last_name" : "Doe"
},
{
    "id" : 2,
    "first_name" : "Bob",
    "last_name" : "Smith"
},
{
    "id" : 3,
    "first_name" : "Jane",
    "last_name" : "Doe"
}
]
```

Here I want to Use the MySQL Tables as JSON Using ASP.net/Restfulweb services,So that it can be used in the part of Android and iPhone.

Any Suggestion please,

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example

[How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-60-sec)

Comment: Its Ok @Sakir Sir its fine I know about this But i want to use MySQL data not Hard code data sir,..

Comment: hardcode data?? what u mean ?I guess u wanna use datasource directlly inside the restful service?

Comment: Yes sir, I mean What ever the Data avaliable in MySQL Tables it should Display,.